# XAML Animation not working properly after moving from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm baffled. This is the relevant XAML code:

```
<Button Content="Got it" 
        Name="ButtonAnimate" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
        Height="32" 
        Margin="0,0,10,10" 
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
        Width="108" 
        Click="ButtonAnimate_Click" >
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Name="AnimationWidth"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="WindowMain"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                        From="415"
                        To="985"
                        Duration="0:0:0.3"
                        RepeatBehavior="1x"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Name="AnimationHeight"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="WindowMain"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                        From="245"
                        To="550"
                        Duration="0:0:0.3"
                        RepeatBehavior="1x"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

A simple button that once clicked animates the WindowMain height and width.

It was working perfectly in .NET 3.5.

But when I changed to .NET 4.5 it stopped working. Either one or the other, but not both at same time.

Does anyone have any idea?